# Migration of dhcp server from windows 2008 server R2 to Linux Server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-server-2008, debian

Right now we are running dhcp server on windows 2008 r2 server. We are planning to migrate it to debian / ubuntu based system.

can any one tell me how to migrate the scopes & filters which are presently there on windows server to linux system.

Answer (score 0):

I've made that transtion recently, and - just by hands. First, it was a chance to re-check the config, second - I've moved DHCP to two-servers fail-over scheme, so it worth to keep eyes on it.

How many items do you need to import/copy? In fact I've never heard of any tools for that, maybe due to very little need for.